# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)

Tags: java, zip

I'm getting this error when doing this (relatively simple) piece of code:

```
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(fn);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> eze = zf.entries();
    while (eze.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry ze = eze.nextElement();
        System.out.println(ze.getName());
    }
    zf.close();
```

Actually. Interestingly enough, I get it on java-sun-6u32 and java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64, but java-sun-7u4 succeeds. unzip itself seems to handle it fine. I'm guessing that means that these zipfiles are perhaps created by some newer version of zip that java 7 understands, but that previous versions do not. But, any insight would be appreciated. Also, since in production I don't really have the option of using java 7, any way of making earlier versions of java understand this new version of zip (if that in fact *is* what the problem is, of course.)

Thanks!

Comment: *sigh*, unfortunately, I can't.. The files in question are ginormous (707 megs) and I'm not producing them.

Comment: Hmm.. However: I can do 7z l -slt whatever.zip and get
`
    7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
    p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)
    Listing archive: ./081212j400-13_file1of3.zip
    --
    Path = ./081212j400-13_file1of3.zip
    Type = zip
    64-bit = +
    Physical Size = 707951519
`


Hm. I can _not_ seem to format that properly. Hopefully it still comes across tho.

Comment: If you're on *nix, what does `file your.zip` say? Or you can just chop off first 512 kb or so off file and place somewhere.

Comment: ahh, it seems to be *zip64* :) AFAIR, for java6 you will have to resort to external library (such as http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html)

Comment: @barti_ddu, if you make that into an answer, I'll upvote you, and declare it the right answer.. Thanks!

Comment: Not at all, your guesses where perfectly correct; good luck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`7z l -slt` output provided in your comment is quite useful:

> Type = zip 64-bit

gives a hint, that it's *ZIP64* (version 4.5 of *ZIP* specification). However, though *Java7* supports it, this support is not backported to *Java6* at the moment and you will have to resort to external library such as Apache [Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html).

P.S. For reference, `file test.zip` would output something like

```
test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v4.5 to extract
```

Comment: For me the file format was correct but the JAR exceeded 100MB which was tripping up some setting on our cluster. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Zip tools like 7zip automatically change to 64bit when the zip size exceeds 4GB (obviously)