# catalina.LifecycleException on starting maven project with Eclipse neon

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am running my maven project on Eclipse neon and getting the following exception. This is a rest service using postgresql.

```
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@f2fc964]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@f2fc964]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4832)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4964)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 13 more

Mar 28, 2017 12:08:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
```

I have not added any files to my WEB-INF\lib folder.

My pom.xml file is as follows..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.ideation.server</groupId>
   <artifactId>IdeationServer</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
         <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

As I am new to java I am not sure whether all those dependencies in the pom.xml are needed or not. I am not getting any error in my source files. Following is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>IdeationServer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I also have a rest-servlet.xml file and an applicationContext.xml. Contents of the both files are same. I am not sure whether I need both these files or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ideation.server" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ideation" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="quest123" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Following is my project structure..

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzG7F.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipError: invalid CEN header (bad signature)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536279/java-util-zip-ziperror-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536279/java-util-zip-ziperror-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453263/compile-error-in-maven2-invalid-cen-header-bad-signature