# "invalid CEN header (bad signature)" when extracting a 4GB+ file from a zip archive using Java 8 jar command

Tags: java, java-8, jar, zip, large-files

I have a zip file that contains 5 files. Four of the files are small (a few kB), but one file is larger than 4GB. I'm aware of [JDK-4681995](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4681995), which added large file support (64-bit zip support) to Java starting in Java 7. I'm using 64 bit Java 8 on Windows 8.1:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>java -version
java version "1.8.0_212"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b10, mixed mode)
```

The zip file size is as follows:

```
07/07/2019  10:18 AM       503,966,751 snapshot-20190707.zip
```

The contents of the zip file are:

```
07/07/2019  09:53 AM                67 database.sha1
07/07/2019  09:51 AM     4,508,840,068 database.sql
07/07/2019  09:53 AM                74 database_schema.sha1
07/07/2019  09:51 AM            36,386 database_schema.sql
07/07/2019  09:51 AM            45,280 backup.log
```

If I try to extract the 4GB file, I encounter an exception that *looks* exactly like the [Java 7 exception for 64-bit zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22536279/2074605):

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>jar xvf snapshot-20190707.zip database.sql
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:126)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:1004)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:305)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

Is there any way to extract a 4GB+ file from a 64-bit zip archive using the Java 8+ `jar` command?

Comment: Did you try that file with any other tool? Looks like you have a corrupted file...which is weird because you can extract the entire content.

Comment: Yes, the SHA-1 hash was verified by several different tools on two different platforms, and the file can be extracted with 7zip and Windows explorer, as well as unzip on Linux. The jar command fails with the same error on both Windows and Linux. I've reproduced the problem with several zip files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception is caused by bug [JDK-8223811](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223811) in Java 8, which is triggered by the `-f` flag. The submitter re-created the problem using:

```
jar xvf archive.zip *
```

From a comment on the bug report (May 19, 2019):

> This is only reproducible on JDK 8 versions. It is fixed in JDK 9 and
>   above and is not an issue in the latest JDK 11, 12 or 13.

The workaround for Java 8 is to avoid specifying an individual file when using the `-f` flag, and to simply extract *all* files in the archive:

This version of the command successfully extracts all files without any problems:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>jar xvf snapshot-20190707.zip
 inflated: backup.log
 inflated: database_schema.sha1
 inflated: database_schema.sql
extracted: database.sha1
 inflated: database.sql
```