# Oracle loadjava JSch

Tags: java, oracle, jsch, loadjava

I am wondering if using **loadjava** to load the Java package called **JSch.jar** in an Oracle database and then loading another .java file, that utilizes the JSch package to connect over SSH, would be able to be executed within an Oracle database through a function or procedure.

I ask this before trying because I need to reach out to a DBA to try and load everything. I want to make sure it is doable because I am not very skilled in java as of yet and wouldn't know if something was impossible or if it just needs fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes

Use something like:

```
loadjava -user USERNAME/PASSWORD@SID JSch.jar
```

Then create a static class method which uses the classes loaded from the Jar file:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED MyJavaSource AS
import org.millea9805.jsch.JSchSomething;

public class MyClass {
    public static String function_name()
    {
        JSchSomething.doSomething();
        return "Something";
    }
}
/
```

Then you can create a PL/SQL wrapper around the static Java method:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DO_SOMETHING()
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'MyClass.function_name() return java.lang.String';
/
```

A more detailed example using the XZ library to unzip BLOBs is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249878/how-to-read-and-extract-zip-entries-from-java-sql-blob-type-zip-file-without-hav/59250531#59250531).