# How to resolve deprecation on Unzip Blob Java Source running on PL/SQL?

Tags: java, oracle

Based on this answer: [How to read and extract zip entries from java.sql.Blob type zip file without having FileInputStream or filepath as a string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249878/how-to-read-and-extract-zip-entries-from-java-sql-blob-type-zip-file-without-hav).

An error is being thrown about **a deprecated API**.

Reproduction of steps:

1. Database Oracle JDK Version:

`SELECT dbms_java.get_jdk_version FROM dual;`

Result: 1.8.0_341

2. loadjava

`call dbms_java.loadjava('/tmp/xz-1.8.jar');`

Result: Call completed

`call dbms_java.loadjava('/tmp/commons-compress-1.10.jar');`

Result: Call completed

3. Create the java source `CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED UNZIP AS` ... like the answer the thread referenced.
4. The following error is presented:

> Java Source UNZIP criado
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
> --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 0/0       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 0/0       Note:
> UNZIP uses or overrides a deprecated API. Erros: verifique o log do
> compilador

How could I solve this deprecated APIs problem?

Comment: Try compiling outside of Oracle using [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html) with the `-Xlint:deprecation` option. That may give you more details on which part of the code is using the deprecated API.

Answer (score 0):

Download (and if necessary build) `xz-1.9`, `commons-compress-1.21` and `ojdbc11` (these are the latest versions but you can download earlier versions if required, and the OJDBC jar should match the database version you are using). Then, within the `/path/to/your/code/` directory, put the built jar files into the `lib` sub-directory.

Create the file `Unzip.java`, again within the `/path/to/your/code/` directory, that has the contents:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveException;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Blob;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorException;
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorStreamFactory;

public class Unzip {
  public static Array listFiles(
      final Blob file
  )
  throws java.sql.SQLException
  {
    final ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    if ( file != null &&  file.length() > 0 )
    {
      ArchiveInputStream ais = null;
      try
      {
        InputStream stream = file.getBinaryStream();
        try {
          stream = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream( stream );
        }
        catch ( CompressorException e ){}
        ais = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream( stream );
        ArchiveEntry entry;
        while( ( entry = ais.getNextEntry() ) != null )
        {
          if ( entry.isDirectory() || entry.getSize() == 0 )
            continue;
          files.add( entry.getName() );
        }
      }
      catch ( ArchiveException e ){
        files.add( "ERROR: " + e.getMessage() );
      }
      catch ( IOException e ){
        files.add( "ERROR: " + e.getMessage() );
      }
      finally
      {
        try { if ( ais != null ) ais.close(); } catch( IOException e ){}
      }
    }

    final String[] fs = new String[ files.size() ];
    files.toArray( fs );
    final Connection conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
    return ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST", fs);
  }

  public static Blob unzip(
    final Blob file,
    final String path
  )
  throws java.sql.SQLException
  {
    ArchiveInputStream ais = null;
    Blob extractedFile     = null;
    Connection conn        = null;
    if ( file != null && file.length() > 0 && path != null )
    {
      try {
        InputStream stream = file.getBinaryStream();
        try {
          stream = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream( stream );
        }
        catch ( CompressorException e ){}
        ais = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream( stream );
        ArchiveEntry entry;
        while( ( entry = ais.getNextEntry() ) != null ){
          if ( !entry.getName().equals( path ) )
            continue;

          final byte[] bytes = new byte[8096];
          long pos = 1;
          int len;

          conn = new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
          extractedFile = conn.createBlob();

          while ( ( len = ais.read( bytes ) ) > 0 ) {
            extractedFile.setBytes( pos, bytes, 0, len );
            pos += len;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      catch ( final ArchiveException e ){}
      catch ( final IOException e ){}
      finally
      {
        try { if ( ais != null ) ais.close(); } catch( final IOException e ){}
        try { if ( conn != null ) conn.close(); } catch( final SQLException e ){}
      }
    }
    return extractedFile;
  }
}
```

Then run `javac -cp "lib/*" Unzip.java` to build it; it should compile without errors.

If it does then:

1. Unload any existing versions of the XZ and Commons Compress libraries from your Oracle database.
2. Use `loadjava` (or an equivalent) to load the XZ and Commons Compress jars that you used as dependencies to compile the java class.
3. In Oracle, load the java using

   ```sql
   CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED UNZIP AS
   <paste the working java code here>
   /
   ```
4. Create the wrapper functions:

   ```sql
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNZIP_LIST_FILES(
     zipfile  IN BLOB
   )
   RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA
   NAME 'Unzip.listFiles( java.sql.Blob ) return java.sql.Array';
   /
   SHOW ERRORS;
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNZIP(
     zipfile  IN BLOB,
     filePath IN VARCHAR2
   )
   RETURN BLOB
   AS LANGUAGE JAVA
   NAME 'Unzip.unzip( java.sql.Blob, java.lang.String ) return java.sql.Blob';
   /
   SHOW ERRORS;
   /
   ```

Then you should be able to use it in your code.

---

*Note: The Java code works outside the database but loading into the database is untested as I do not currently have a Java-enabled database; however the principal is to test the Java outside the database using the correct versions of the Jar files and then when it is working load it into the database.*