# Concat Two Zip Files From Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, concatenation

I have two or more files that get created on the server. I want to concatenate them from the database. But Couldn't find anything that gets the job done.
Below is the current code.

```
begin
for i in (select filename from server_files where filename like '%EMPLOYEE%.dat%')
loop 
zip_file(i.filename,i_dir);
end loop;
end;
```

It creates the following files

```
EMPLOYEE_1.dat.gz
EMPLOYEE_2.dat.gz
EMPLOYEE_3.dat.gz
```

Now, I am not able to concat all three into one file via database.

Comment: See also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249878/1509264 for an example of reading from zip archives that you may be able to adapt/extend to write zip archives.